# Android application like the Mobile Browser Version

Tags: android

I have a question about creating an Android application. 
I have a website (dating service) and it has "Desktop Version" and "Mobile Browser Version". These two versions differ in design and few functions (but they are one, one registration for one user). I want to make an Android application like the "Mobile Browser Version", so that it is also connected with my website (one registration for one user).
How to do it?

I installed Android Studio and connected to Firebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do two things (easy and hard )

1) easy way is if your website is responsive then you can use a webview of android with your website link that don't need any other customization.Just one splash screen and a webview in Mainactivity.

2) (Hard one) you can make API to pull and push data from/to database,this need, you have to make app from scratch and need some times.For this you must have deep knowledge about Retrofit,Recycleview etc

Comment: Thank you, regarding webview of android, which version is imported "Desktop Version" or "Mobile Browser Version"?

Comment: Welcome,you have to use mobile version.Webview is very easy to integrate here is a sample code just 3 line of code and your site is ported to app :)                                         WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl(url);

Comment: After compilation, such an error on Virtual Device
->
webpage could not be loaded because:
net :: ERR_ACCESS_DENIED

Comment: Make sure internet permission is given and add android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" if you use http website.If it help you then pls accept the answer

Comment: please accept the answer and give some reputation to me :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have already have a database connected with your website then you need to make an API service to connect android application with your website. You can restrict users having multiple accounts by making their email or mobile number primary key if you have a relational database. or you can use firebase but you also need to connect the website with the firebase account otherwise it will act like a separate service.

Comment: Thank you, now in - Firebase Templates - is going checking my "domain confirmation". After "domain confirmation" a new window or offer opens? is there any documentation about this in Firebase (about connecting an application to a website)?

Comment: @BookBook Go under the JavaScript section. JavaScript is essentially for websites.

Comment: Check the firebase official doc https://firebase.google.com/docs